# QlikView - Loading specific files from remote server

Tags: csv, qlikview

I'm trying to solve this problem for a long time, but now I have to ask for your help.

I have one QVD file on my local PC named e.g. server001_CPU.qvd and on remote servers I have shared folder with many files of many types. There are also files named server001_CPU_YYYYMMDD.csv (e.g. server001_CPU_20140806.csv) that are generated every day and that have same structure as local qvd file. They have column DATE. What I need is (in loading script) to check last DATE in local file and load remote files starting from that day to today and then concatenate it together. Something like this:

```
CPU:
LOAD * FROM server001_CPU.qvd

LET vMAX = Max(DATE) FROM CPU

DO WHILE vMAX <= Today()

  CPU:
  LOAD * FROM serverpath/server001_CPU_$(vMAX).csv

LOOP
```

I'm really trying but I'm new to QV and it has strange logic for me. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below script snippet which should do what you need.

What this does is first open your existing data set (in the QVD), and then finds the maximum date and stores it in table `MaxCPUDate`. This maximum value is then read into a variable and the table is dropped.

This "Max Date" value is then subtracted from today's date to determine the number of loops to execute to load the individual files. The loop variable is added on to the "Max Date" value to create the filename to load.

```
CPU:
LOAD 
    *
FROM server001_CPU.qvd (qvd);

MaxCPUDate:
LOAD DISTINCT
    max(DATE) as MaxDate
RESIDENT CPU;

LET vMaxCPUDate = peek('MaxDate',-1,'MaxCPUDate');

DROP TABLE MaxCPUDate;    

FOR vFileNum = 0 TO (num(Today()) - $(vMaxCPUDate))

    LET Filename ='serverpath/server001_CPU_' & date($(vMaxCPUDate) + $(vFileNum),'YYYYMMDD') & '.csv';

    CONCATENATE (CPU)
    LOAD
        *
    FROM $(Filename) (txt, codepage is 1252, embedded labels, delimiter is ',', msq);

NEXT
```